# Is the Queryable right way to getting elements from the service?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core

I created a service that has to get Elements from the database. During the Development Life cycle, the service has grown, and right now I have a lot of methods that have getting elements per ID, Category, Name, etc.

For now, I was trying to not returning IEnumerable, but Iqueryable, and building Where clause in the methods, that is calling the service, but I don't think so this is the right way to do this. Of course, if somewhere the Where clause is duplicated, I am trying to move the duplicated code in the service and use the Iqueryable which was created before.

OLD:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Element>> GetElementsByIds(List<int> elementsIds)
        {
            var elements = await _context.Elements
                .Include(e => e.ElementCategories)
                .Include(e=>e.ElementSth)
                .Where(e => elementsIds.Contains(e.Id))
                .ToListAsync();

            if (!elements.Any())
            {
                throw new NotFoundException(nameof(Element), elementsIds);
            }

            return elements;
        }

        public async Task<IEnumerable<Element>> GetElementsPerCategory(string categoryName)
        {
            var elements = await _context.Elements
                .Include(e => e.ElementCategories)
                .Include(e=>e.ElementSth)
                .Where(c=>c.Category.Name == categoryName)
                .ToListAsync();

            if (!elements.Any())
            {
                throw new NotFoundException(nameof(Element), elementsIds);
            }

            return elements;
        }
```

NOW:

```
public async Task<IQueryable<Element>> GetElementsByIds(List<int> elementsIds)
        {
            var elements = _context.Elements
                .Include(e => e.ElementCategories)
                .Include(e=>e.ElementSth);

            return elements;
        }
```

I want to refactor the service and create future services in a better way. Have you any experience with the problem?

Comment: Your new code won't even compile because you're returning `List<T>`, not `IQueryable<T>`. If you want the `Where` to be dynamic from outside the method, then consider passing in the where expression instead.

Comment: Yea, you are right that it will not compile. I will edit it. I was thinking about to use Expression as a parameter of the method but I am not sure if is it right.

Comment: Just add `Expression<Func<Element, bool>> predicate = null` to the parameters and do `if(predicate != null) elements = elements.Where(predicate);` but use your original code, don't return the queryable.

Comment: This is a bad practice to return `IQueryable` in public method to a higher level because this way you are exposing the database behavior to a higher level. If the only difference here in the predicate you could implement a private method which accepts a predicate as argument and use it in your public methods which then return `IEnumerable`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exposing the `IQueryable<>` directly is a very different thing since it basically allows doing whatever with the database. Depending on what is actually being queried, even your `.Include()` calls may be ignored.

Exposing the queryable in internal services is a good way to write very efficient queries (since those will then just get what they actually need). For less-internal or public facing APIs, I would really recommend not to expose the queryable directly to keep the control.

That being said, if you just want to avoid code duplication, you can introduce a helper method that does the actual querying and just pass different filters in your methods:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Element>> GetElementsByIds(List<int> elementsIds)
{
    return await GetElementsInternal(_context.Elements.Where(e => elementsIds.Contains(e.Id)));
}

public async Task<IEnumerable<Element>> GetElementsPerCategory(string categoryName)
{
    return await GetElementsInternal(_context.Elements.Where(e => e.Category.Name == categoryName));
}

private async Task<IEnumerable<Element>> GetElementsInternal(IQueryable<Element> queryable)
{
    var elements = queryable
        .Include(e => e.ElementCategories)
        .Include(e => e.ElementSth)
        .ToListAsync();

    if (!elements.Any())
    {
        throw new NotFoundException(nameof(Element), elementsIds);
    }

    return elements;
}
```